# Nightwatch error message

Tags: nightwatch.js

Can I change text output of failed tests in Nightwatch.js?

> × Password Input in "Log in" Pop-up (#password) visible for 16000ms  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"

I expect:

> × Password Input in "Log in" Pop-up (#password) NOT FOUND for 16000ms

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are using. If you are using any of the `expect` commands then no, you cannot customize the message. However, if you are using `assert` then you can.

```
browser.assert.visible('.should_be_visible', 'This is my custom message');
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but the above answer is not strictly correct. While some expect commands do not support an optional message, there are also those that do. You can look through the api docs which will tell you which commands support messages and which do not here: http://nightwatchjs.org/api

What is important to note is that optional messages as shown in the answer above will output regardless of pass/fail, meaning they are not strictly 'error messages'.

One way to adapt this is through your naming, for example if a test is looking for an element on a page, do not use a message of 'Cannot find element' as this will display even if the element is found successfully. Instead use something like 'Looking for element'...

```
.waitForElementVisible('#element', 1000, 'Looking for something on some page')
```

This at least tells the user what the test was trying to do when it failed but also makes sense when it passes. Hope that helps.